# CONNECTION SOCKET.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, websocket, socket.io

I've been stuck for a few days now with a socket.io problem, more precisely between server to client.
On the client side, (Angular) I can emit an event, the server can grab and execute all the logic, but after the server to the client it doesn't show signs of life.
I've already expressed all the events, I've reformulated all the settings as it says in the documentation and nothing works, can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

"socket.io": "^4.5.1"

"socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",

ANGULAR (CLIENT-SIDE)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketIoService {

  socket: Socket;

  constructor() {}

  connect(token: string, userName: string){
    this.socket = io(environment.path.hermsUrl, {
      query: {
       token,
       userName
      }
    });
  }

  disconnect(){
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }

  sendMessage(msg: any) {
    this.socket.emit('send-message', (msg));
  }

  getConversation(){
    this.socket.on('update-conversation', (conversation)=> {
      console.log('############################################');
    });
  }


}
```

NODE.JS (SERVER-SIDE)

```
require('dotenv').config();
require('./Helpers/init_mongodb');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const chatController = require('./Controllers/chat.controller');
const Chat = require('./Models/chat.model');
const app = express();
const httServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const { verifyAccessToken } = require('./Helpers/jwt_token');
const userRoute = require('./Routes/user.routes');
const eventRoute = require('./Routes/event.routes');
const chatRoute = require('./Routes/chat.routes');
const decode = require('jwt-decode');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5005;

const io = require('socket.io')(httServer, {
  cors: {
    origins: ["*"]
  }
});

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/path/user', userRoute);
app.use('/path/event', eventRoute);
app.use('/path/chat', chatRoute);

app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  next(createError.NotFound('THIS ROUTE DOES NOT EXIST'))
});

app.get('/', verifyAccessToken, async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('HELLO THERE')
});


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    res.send({
      error: {
        status: err.status || 500,
        message: err.message,
      },
    })
});


io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  
  const decodedObj = decode(socket.handshake.query.token);
  socket.id = decodedObj.aud;
  const userName = socket.handshake.query.userName;

  console.log("========= SOCKET.IO CONNECTED =========");
  console.log("");
  console.log("USERNAME: " + userName);
  console.log("ID: " + socket.id);
  console.log("");
  console.log("=======================================");


  socket.on('send-message', async (message) => {

    try{

        const chatId = message.chatId;
        const decodedObj = decode(message.sender);
        const senderId = decodedObj.ID;
        const userSocketId = message.userId;

        const date = new Date();
        const day = date.getDate();
        const month = date.getMonth();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const hour = date.getHours();
        const minuts = date.getMinutes();

        const sendingDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minuts;

        const newMsg = {
          msgType: message.typeOfMsg,
          message: message.msg,
          date: sendingDate,
          sender: senderId
        }

        const conversation = await Chat.findById(chatId);

        if(!conversation){
          throw createError.NotFound();
        }

        conversation.messages.push(newMsg);

        const updateConversation = await Chat.findByIdAndUpdate(chatId, conversation);

        if(!updateConversation){
          throw createError.InternalServerError();
        }

        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!! SEND EMIT FROM SOCKET/SERVER !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        io.emit('update-conversation', 'FROM SERVER');
        io.emit('update-conversation');
        io.local.emit('update-conversation');
        io.local.emit('update-conversation', 'FROM SERVER');
        socket.emit('update-conversation', 'FROM SERVER');
        socket.emit('update-conversation');
        socket.broadcast('update-conversation', 'FROM SERVER');
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!! EMIT SENDED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  });



  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("########### SOCKET.IO DISCONNECTED ###########");
    console.log("");
    console.log("USERNAME: " + userName);
    console.log("ID: " + socket.id);
    console.log("");
    console.log("##############################################");
  });

});


httServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`SERVER RUNNING ON PORT ${PORT}`);
})
```

Comment: Why does your question say "NODE.JS (CLENT-SIDE)".  Isn't this the "server"?

Comment: One thing that is wrong is `catch(error) { next(error)}` in your `socket.on('send-message', ...)` is not correct.  There is no `next()` defined in that scope.

Comment: Where is `sendMessage()` called from in the browser?  Is it, by any chance, called from the processing of a `<form>`.

Comment: @jfriend00
You are right, i already corrected these two errors, thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Your `getConversation()` method will likely not work.  That needs to be called once and only once when your client is initialized.  You can't call it later and expect it to go back into the past and get previous messages that have already arrived.  Basically, we need to see enough client-side code so we can follow the flow of events from where `sendMessage()` is called to where you're expecting a response back from the server.

Comment: @jfriend00
Yes.. sendMessage() is called from the browser but not from a form.
That emit event, from client-side to the serve works fine, the problem is when i call from the server to the client, if you see i use all the event emitter if the socket.io on the serve and anyone reach the client-side

Comment: Yes, I know it's server to client you're having trouble with, but many times the issue is that the client has moved onto a new page and thus the socket.io connection it originally had is no longer connected and that's why the client doesn't seem to get the message.  That's what I'm trying to look into as a possible cause, but you've not disclosed enough of what happens on the client to know if this could be the case or not.  If you log all connects and disconnects on both client and server, you will sometimes be able to see whether this is happening or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 I already understood what you wanted to ask.
The user is always online, as long as he doesn't close the window, he doesn't change pages even after sending the message

Comment: Then, please show the code where `getConversation()` is called.  If your socket is staying connected, the message is getting sent.  It has to be something in the client code that causes you to not receive it.  You aren't showing any of the relevant code there so as of this moment, I can't help any further.  I'd like to be able to follow the entire client code flow from when you send a message to the server to when you expect to receive it back.  Said differently, the next most likely place for the problem to be is in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: @jfriend00 getConversation() is not being called by anyone

Comment: Then, this code `this.socket.on('update-conversation', ...)` never runs so you're simply not listening for the `update-conversation` message that your server is sending to you.

Comment: @jfriend00
How do gonna make to call an client-side function from the server?

Comment: You don't call client code from the server.  You install the listener in the client code once, long before it is needed when you set up/initialize your client.

Comment: @jfriend00
How u do that?
I follow the socket.io documentation and doesnt see nothing about that

Comment: @jfriend00
It's already working, I just now realized how it works. Thanks to the fact that you told me that I would have to install the Listener the moment I initialize the connection. Thank you very much, it's already working, I didn't understand the idea

Answer (score 1):

It appears you aren't yet listening for the `update-conversation` message in the client.  Thus, when the server sends it, you don't have any client code to actually receive it.

You need to register the listener `this.socket.on('update-conversation', ...)` on the client-side when you first create the socket.io connection.  Then, it will be ready to receive that message whenever the server sends that message.